# Unable to connect to remote server using SSH key in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ssh, phpseclib

I am trying to connect with remote server using **SSH Key**. I am generating SSH keypair using `phpseclib 2.0` and I storing keys in the database. Here is how I am trying to connect.

```
Config::set('remote.connections.production.host',$server->ip);
Config::set('remote.connections.production.username',$server->username);
Config::set('remote.connections.production.keytext',$server->meta()->where('meta_key','private_key')->first()->meta_value);
```

I have public key corresponding to the private key I am using in remote server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. The permissions for `.ssh` directory is `700` and permissions for `authorized_keys` is `600` which is perfect.

First I thought this might be a `\r\n` issue but then I tried to remove all `\r\n` from the private key before connecting but I am still getting `unable to connect to remote server`. I don't know where the issue is. I am trying since last two days without luck.

I think SSH key gets damaged once it enters into the database. Here is how I am generating and storing SSH keypair in the database.

```
$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(RSA::PUBLIC_FORMAT_OPENSSH);
$keys = $rsa->createKey(2048);
$privateKey = $keys['privatekey'];
$publicKey = $keys['publickey'];

$server->meta()->create([
     'meta_key' => 'private_key',
     'meta_value' => $privateKey
]);

$server->meta()->create([
    'meta_key' => 'public_key',
    'meta_value' => $publicKey
]);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Keys are being generated for sure because I can see it in the database.

Comment: One possibility is that your column definition is bad. Like maybe you're doing VARCHAR(255) for the column you're trying to insert the private key into (255 isn't big enough). How are you trying to connect to the remote server? Are you using phpseclib to connect or another SSH client? If you're using phpseclib or PuTTY you can get logs that show the raw packets that are being sent to and fro. I'll tell you how to get at the logs pending confirmation of the client that you're using.

Comment: Hi. I have `text` datatype, not `varchar`. So it is not a bad column definition issue.

Comment: I am using `laravelcollective/remote` to connect with the remote server.

Comment: Do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);`. That'll output the SSH logs in real time. Then copy / paste the logs onto pastebin.org

Comment: Here is the log -> https://pastebin.com/LTAPm96j

Comment: The logs confirm what you're saying. The server is rejecting the key. Normally with SSH the public key needs to go into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Can you confirm that it's in there?